# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) when plotting a js chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, c3.js

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

I get the above mentioned error in the following file (script):

```
var Alpha_access = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#alpha_access',
    data: {
        url: '../static/CSV/Chart_data/alpha_access.csv?rnd='+(new Date).getTime(),
        x: 'Access grade',
        types: {
            Alpha:'scatter',
            Regression: 'line'
        },
    },
    axis: {
        y: {
            label: {
                text: "Alpha",
                position: "outer-middle"
            },
            min: 0.1,
            max: 0.9,
            padding: {top: 46},
            tick: {outer: false}
        },
        x: {
            label: {
                text: "Access grade PAU",
                position: "outer-center"
            },
            min: 9,
            max: 14,
            padding: {right: 0.2,left:0.15},
            tick: {
                outer: false,
                count:1,
                fit:false,
                values: [9,10,11,12,13,14]
            }
        }
    },
    size: {
        height: 400,
        width: 800
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true
    },
    legend: {
        show: true,
        position: 'bottom'
    }
})

d3.csv('../static/CSV/Chart_data/alpha_access.csv?rnd='+(new Date).getTime(),function(data){
    var d1 = data[0];
    var d2 = data[1];

    var a = (d2["Regression"] - d1["Regression"])/(d2["Access grade"] - d1["Access grade"]);
    var b = d2["Regression"] - (d2["Access grade"]*a);

    b = (Math.round(b*1000)/1000);
    a = (Math.round(a*1000)/1000);
    document.getElementById("equation2").innerHTML = "Alpha = " + a + "·Acces grade PAU + " + b;
  })
```

I have a file which does exactly the same with another parameter (instead of alpha) and works fine. I have compared and reviewed the script and it looks fine. Any ideas?

Comment: can you paste the complete error, as it will show line number of unwanted token ')'  location

Comment: You might want to use a linter. Pasting your code to jslint.com reveals various problems. One being the missing parentheses after the `Date` constructor, which, most likely, is your problem. Use `new Date().getTime()` or, even better, the static method `Date.now()` which will return the same value.